# Azure DevOps service hook authentication

Tags: azure-devops

Currently we have a use case where we have to call the azure function app from Azure DevOps service hooks. We have enabled the AAD authentication on the azure function app, but from azure DevOps the calls are blocked with 401 unauthorized error. We noticed that the webhook url is accepting only basic authentication. Our Azure AD is integrated with okta and I am currently blocked with this. Can some one help with this?

Comment: Thanks...As there is no out of the box solution for this, we have enabled AAD at function app and bypassing the call to this function app with APIM...

Answer (score 0):

> Azure DevOps service hook authentication

I am afraid there is no such way to achieve this at this moment.

Just as you know, the webhook URL only accepts basic authentication. I also create a azure function app, I could access it by the basic authentication, but if I enable the AAD authentication on that azure function app, I could not access it and get the 401 unauthorized:

[image]

Currently, we could not change the authentication method for the service hook. You could try to change the value to Log in with `Microsoft Account` instead of `Azure Active Directory`  for the option `Action to take when request not authenticated` drop down. And you could add your request for this feature on our UserVoice site (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21 ), which is our main forum for product suggestions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks...As there is no out of the box solution for this, we have enabled AAD at function app and bypassing the call to this function app with APIM...